# App Engine - How to create project in region us-central

Tags: google-app-engine

I need to create a new project on Google App Engine in the region "us-central" since my SQL database is located in this region and I can not connect projects from other regions to the SQL database.

If I create a new project, it is located by default in EU. There is no option to choose the region during project creation. See the attached screenshot. Is there a way to create a project in "us-central"?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Setting the server location](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/#server-location):

> When you create your project, you can specify the [location](https://cloud.google.com/docs/geography-and-regions) from
>   which it will be served. In the new project dialog, click on the link
>   to **Show Advanced Options**, and select a location from the pulldown
>   menu:

But it seems the documented project region selection procedure is changing, as the **Show Advanced Options** link is, as you observed, nowhere to be seen anymore.

Empirically I have discovered the following method. But being undocumented it may change at any time, so YMMV.

Just click on the `CREATE` link in the screen you're showing.

You'll see a screen asking you to choose the app language (the popup is a bit flakey, I had to reload the page to actually be able to make the selection):

[image]

After you select the language you'll see the location selection screen:

[image]

It seems the app created sequence is now persisted, you'll also be automatically directed to the correct screen if, at any time, you attempt to go to the GAE app settings for the newly created app.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was searching forever, but I already deployed something to that project and therefore this screen did not show up. So remember: First select the location, then deploy :)