# Where do I set the region for my new GAE project?

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, phpmyadmin, google-cloud-sql

I am at a complete loss with regards to the region of my Google App Engine project. My default project (the only one left after I deleted the rest) is supposedly in the region `us-east1`. But I want it to be in Europe.

I am new to `Google App Engine` and the `Google Cloud` in general. I want to follow the simple tutorial here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/phpmyadmin-on-app-engine

My SQL server is in Europe and I was under the impression that an app could not be in a different region than the SQL server but I was wrong. I went through the tutorial before and had it up an running. My app `phpMyAdmin` was stored in `us-east1` and I think this was the reason why it was painfully slow.

I am now looking for a way to get the region to be `europe-west1-d`.
Can someone give me guidance where I can set this. I read somewhere that it might be set in the `php.ini` but I am not sure.

Comment: Have a look at this recent Answer from Dan Cornilescu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41141494/app-engine-how-to-create-project-in-region-us-central

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the location/Region of a project in Google app engine after you create it. You can only choose the location/Region when you are creating a new project.

Comment: Yeah, I was aware of that but I wasn't aware of where to set the region in the first place. I found out where it was from the comment above.