# Change region in new App Engine Flexible project

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I created a new App Engine Flexible Node.js project with a custom runtime (the dockerfile is just based on the node app engine image for now).
The first time I deployed it I could select a region and had chosen for EU.
But I now get this error because the flexible runtime is not yet available in Europe:

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Flexible Environment
>   deployments are not supported in the apps region 'europe-west'.

I'm now trying to change my region, but I have no idea where I can do that.
I did gcloud init again and had chosen for us-west1.
In ~/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_default I can see that the zone is 'us-west1-b' and the region is 'us-west1'.

But after a new gcloud app deploy I get the same error.
Where is the region stored? How can I change it without removing the project.

Answer (score 1):

The selection of a GAE project region is typically done at app **creation** time, not deployment time, see [App Engine - How to create project in region us-central](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41141494/app-engine-how-to-create-project-in-region-us-central/41145747#41145747).

But check the comment to that post - it seems it's possible to deploy before selecting the location - I suspect you either actually deployed in a default non-EU location or you didn't deploy a flexible environment app.

Yes, it is possible to change the environment of an app (actually an app's service/module, to be technically correct) from standard to flexible and viceversa at deployment time, depending on the code being deployed.

The region cannot be changed after its initial selection, see [Change GAE application location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589246/change-gae-application-location)

Comment: It seems the creation is done automatically at the first deploy. You can choose a region then, but after that it can't be changed anymore. The strange thing is that the app was not visible in the console. I now deleted the project and restarted.